# Why can't I simplify this pattern match?

Tags: haskell

This works fine:

```
data Possibly a = LolNope | Yeppers a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Possibly where
    fmap f (Yeppers a) = Yeppers (f a)
    fmap _ LolNope = LolNope
```

Repeating the `LolNope` in the last line doesn't look elegant. Replacing the last line with the following doesn't work:

```
fmap _ z = z  -- error: Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’ ...
```

This doesn't work either:

```
fmap _ z@(_) = z  -- error: Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’ ...
```

Why don't they work, and are there alternatives that work?

Comment: You have an alternative that works already: repeat `LolNope`

Comment: Agreed. This is how `Functor Maybe` instance is implemented, and IMO it is nicer than using the catchall `z` because you are explicitly covering all data constructors that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they involve different types:

```
fmap f LolNope = LolNope
--               ^-- Possibly b
--     ^-- Possibly a
--   ^-- a -> b
```

Sure, the runtime representation of these two `LolNope`s is the same in GHC, but this is not enough. Its representation could even coincide with `Nothing`, `()` , `[]`, and other nullary constructors yet none of those are allowed.

IMHO, this is a fine example about the type system being stricter than actually needed.

In spite of the static constraint, the GHC runtime might choose to re-use the same memory location for `LolNope :: Possibly a` and `LolNope :: Possibly b`. (I can't remember if it actually does...)

Comment: I believe they will share memory locations, yes. The situation is not so great for `Either`. Converting `Right p :: Either x a` to type `Either y a` may necessitate allocating a new `Right` constructor (GHC tries to clear this up in C--, I think, but it's not perfect). Some GHC gurus were talking about trying to find a fix a while back, but I don't think they ever did--it's a pretty bad fit for System FC.